# Call specific runner for Git script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How I can call a specific runner for CI job. **Problem**: I have default runners and now I have to install my local runner and run tests on it. But I haven't a possibility to turn off runners on the Git because the whole project builds on remote drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tags` to tag a runner, when you register it. And you can specify that your job will only run on runners with this tags.

eg. you tagged your runner with 'fancy-example' than you can use it like

```
build:
   tags:
      - fancy-example
   script:
      - echo Hello
```

See the gitLab docs for more detailed examples and explanations:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#tags